# "There is no word so sweet as mother" or "There is no word as sweet as mother"

Tags: as, so

Which sentence is correct?

1. There is no word so sweet as mother
2. There is no word as sweet as mother

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct. Up to about 100 years ago) only 'no word **so** sweet as' was judged correct by the writers of grammar books, and using 'as' in the first place was considered an error. Nowadays both are acceptable.

[As versus so in negative-comparisons](https://www.macmillandictionaryblog.com/as-versus-so-in-negative-comparisons)

John Williams, the author of the blog I linked to, wrote in a comment:

> As a corpus linguist of philosophical inclinations, I would propose
> the following formula: “If Idea X can be expressed by both Usage Y and
> Usage Z, then, if Y can be shown to be more frequent than Z in
> expressing X, we have no grounds for deeming Y to be unacceptable and
> Z acceptable (though both could be acceptable).”
>
> Or, as Joseph Priestley put it rather more elegantly in 1762: “Those
> who wrote in the language while it was a living one will be accounted
> the standards of it; and even their imperfections must be adopted by
> all who use it after them.”